# No images without autentication on Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, session, authentication

I'm building a web application with Codeigniter. I have some images on my server and I want that only logged users can see them. The login is made with the session class of codeigniter.

I don't want that external users can open the image

> http://www.mywebapp.com/images/privateimage.jpg

Opening this image I have to control if there is a valid codeigniter session and then give the image.

I've tried to made a controller called "images" and I've tried to add a rule in the htaccess file in order to call a function that checks the session and than sends the image to the client, but this

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ index.php?/images/$1 [L]
```

doesn't work. I don't know very well the rules of the htaccess files and I don't know if there are simplier ways to do this, but I want to preserve the correspondence between the url of the image and its position on the web server if it's possible.

Thank you

Comment: Do you not want it to display going directly to the images, when the image is included in a page or both?

Comment: I don't want anyone not logged in can access to this images in any way. If I'm logged the link gives me the image, if I'm not logged the link gives me an error.

Comment: Do you need logged in users to be able to view the images directly? If not, then you can block the images from browser inclusion and do some other changes to make them viewable within your website. Let me know if this is what you're looking for before I provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof Of Concept**

**First Step.**
Put the images folder outside the webserver folder, with this nobody can see the images.

**Second Step.**
Create a controler:

```
<?php
class Viewer extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //here you can check if the user has a session if not die!! XD


}

public function index() {
    //nothing here o blank page
} 


public function see_pic($name) {
    header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    $ruta = "/folder/with/pics/".$name; 
    $im = imagecreatefromJPEG($ruta);
    @ImageJPEG($im);
        @ImageDestroy($im);
}

?>
```

And then when you put the image "http://my_server.com/viewer/see_pic/my_dog.jpg"